# how to calculate PCA loadings in R

Tags: r, pca

I performed a weighted PCA using `{EasyCODA}` r package, but apparently the output doesn't return the loadings for each component.

```
library(easyCODA)
data(veg)
veg.CLR <- CLR(veg)
veg.PCA <- PCA(veg.CLR$LR, weight=F)
summary(veg.PCA)
```

Any idea about how to calculate it in R? Thanks

Comment: Is `veg.PCA$colcoord` what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @DaveArmstrong, this is the column of loadings I think, but they are supposed to range from -1 to +1, and it's not the case here, so something needs to be done to make them vary like this.